# Is there a Chrome extension that allows me to save what I have filled in and help me fill in the webpage the next time I visit it?

Tags: chrome, forms

Say I filled in a form on a web page, and I always have to do this multiple times. Is there a Chrome extension that allows me to save what I have filled in and help me fill in the webpage the next time I visit it?

Comment: Did my answer help @forgodsakehold? –

Answer (score 0):

You should not need an add-on or extension for this. In the settings of Chrome you can find the "Autofill" section. Here you can enable autofill for different types of fields like password or address.

Note that auto-fill may not work if the site creator names the form fields in a strange way.

You find the settings by clicking the three dots in the upper right corner, then choose "settings" and then in the left sidebar. In the current version it is the second sidebar item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an extension that improves the default Chromium autofill, then you could try popular [Autofill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=pl). It improves the experience with following features:

- faster filling
- more input types supported, e.g. selectable fields
- templates/snippets
- website filtering/exclusions

... and many more.